# Swift Mail PHP doesn't send email

Tags: php, swiftmailer

This is the code:

```
require_once '../../../usr/share/php/swift_required.php';

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, "ssl")
  ->setUsername('sender@gmail.com')
  ->setPassword('password');

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Test Subject')
  ->setFrom(array('sender@gmail.com' => 'mr x'))
  ->setTo(array('receiver@hotmail.com' => 'mr y'))
  ->setBody('This is a test mail.');

$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Of course my code includes real e-mail addresses and passwords. What am I missing? When the page opens, the page starts loading for a long time and then nothing happens. I think it is failing at some point due to time-out(can tell from the waiting time). How can I troubleshoot this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Consider checking your server error logs? Or active `error_reporting`, or add `try{} catch{}` to your current code.

Comment: it puts an error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]. Is it not smtp.gmail.com?

Comment: Check your firewall for port to be opened. ;) It is a common issue with email clients, that server has closed outbound port.

Comment: It is a remote server, should I open port 465 on the server?

Comment: Yes, according to gmail's instructions - you should use port 465 or 587.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to open the ports, or allow the ports. Maybe that wasn't the problem or some firewall was blocking it that was out of my reach. I ended up using phpMailer, which was a lot easier for me.